# CSS Doesn't load images?

Tags: css, image

So i have my website, [www.alphenweer.nl](http://alphenweer.nl/index.php), and that uses some images in the template.
Now the images are on the right url, they work fine, but when i load my website the images won't load? You can try it [here](http://alphenweer.nl/index.php). Please help, why won't the images load?

Greetings

Comment: Can you please post relevent part of the code here, I don't feel like digging in your website css ;)

Comment: <http://images.alphenweer.nl/i/gradient-menu-left.png> (first image in first css file) does not work for me, i.e. does not exist on the server. are you sure the urls are correct? (case-sensitive filesystems?)

Comment: Haha, see my answer... I needed to reupload the css files... Sorry =)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I gave a look at your css :

```
#header {
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 985px;
    background-image: url('http://images.alphenweer.nl/i/header-winter.png');
    text-align: center;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Even when I copy the url in my browser, I got a 404, so the image isn't on your webserver.

Comment: Haha, and if you remove the /i and get http://images.alphenweer.nl/header-winter.png, it does work ;)

Comment: There's no such restriction, you do can use an offsite image.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh no! I found my own answer. I needed to reupload the css files, i forgot =)!

God, i'll understand when you guys are gonna thumb down! =)

Answer (score 0):

if other images are loading and some are not loading on same location then it is due to hyphen that you have in your image name.

Hyphen in names gives problem in many places. Not only in CSS but when access database and table tables, directories and file names etc. So, try to avoid hyphen instead use underscore.

But I do not know why hyphen give problem. If anyone know that, pleas share your knowledge.